# VSTO Office (Excel) Add-In - WPF XAML Style, ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, excel, windows-installer, vsto

I want to deploy my VSTO Office Excel-Add-In with the Windows Installer.
I created the Installer and installed the Add-In on a Virtual PC, to test it.
Now i have the Problem, that the Styles not working, but if i debug or run it in Visual Studio it does work.

For example, i created a Style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Snow" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
     </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Now i merge the ResourceDictionary (with the style in it) with the ResourceDictionary of the Window:

```
<Window.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/assembly;component/UI/Resources/Style.xaml" />
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

It does only works after the Setup, when i use Keys for the Styles and set the Style directly to the Control.

---

This is the ResourceDictionary with the Styles (Styles.xaml):

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
     <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Snow" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
     </Style.Setters>
</Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

And here is the "Merge"-ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/ExcelAddIn;component/UI/Resources/Style/Brushes.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/ExcelAddIn;component/UI/Resources/Style/ControlTemplates.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/ExcelAddIn;component/UI/Resources/Style/Styles.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/ExcelAddIn;component/UI/Resources/Style/DataTemplates.xaml" />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

To merge the ResourceDictionary to the Window-Resources, i tried to used:

These are working when i debug/run it with Visual Studio but not after Setup:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/ExcelAddIn;component/UI/Resources/Style/Skin.xaml" />

<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ExcelAddIn;component/UI/Resources/Style/Skin.xaml" />

<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ExcelAddIn;v1.0.0.0;component/UI/Resources/Style/Skin.xaml" />
```

These are generally not working:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/UI/Resources/Style/Skin.xaml" />

<ResourceDictionary Source="/UI/Resources/Style/Skin.xaml" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the uri in the Source property is the problem. Try using [Pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx)

Comment: how are you storing your resources? post the xaml, and also the pack uri you're using