# WPF Resource Dictionary in Excel Addin

Tags: wpf, excel, dictionary, resources

I've been searching a while now and still no closer to a solution. Here's my situation:

I am creating an Excel Addin and want to use WPF to make it look a little better. Natively (as far as I know) Addins have to be WinForm. I started using WPF Element Hosting but the reult is not very good. I then found that adding a WPF Project to the solution works which is great, but now I want to use a Resource Dictionary to keep forms looking the same and reducing inline styles. I just cant get the merged dictionaries to work.

I have tried Pack URI and ;component/..... but neither work.

What am I doing wrong?

-------EDIT-------

I have a Excel Addin Solution called SolutionA
The solution contains 3 Projects:

ProjectA which is an Excel Addin Project which has references to ProjectB and ProjectC

ProjectB which is a WPF Project which has a reference to ProjectC

ProjectC which contains the resource dictionary

Just need to know how to reference the resource dictionary from ProjectB

Comment: How are we to know what you're doing wrong when you haven't showed us what you're doing? Simply mentioning keywords is *not* showing us what you have tried.

Comment: I have edited the question, hope it makes a little more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [Pack URIs in Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28VS.85%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

Basically, you want something a bit like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source=
"pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/FolderName/DictionaryName.xaml" />
```

You will need to change `AssemblyName` to the name of the assembly that your resource file is in and `FolderName` to the name of any folder(s) that your resource file is in and then `DictionaryName` to the name of you resource file. Basically, it's just the relative path to your resource file.

Comment: So using my example it should be: <ResourceDictionary Source=
"pack://application:,,,/ProjectC;component/FolderName/DictionaryName.xaml" /> ?

Comment: I have tried this, and I get a parse exception on the first line that tries to call the StaticResource

Comment: This is how you achieve what you asked. If it is not working, then you must have done something wrong. I'd advise you to actually read the linked page on MSDN to make sure that you're doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing an Excel document customization using WPF controls and MahApps styles. Everything works fine on my virtualized development box using Excel 2013 and a physical Excel 2010 box (both have VS2012 on them).

On other virtualized boxes running Excel 2010 or Excel 2013 the styles do not work. This is when running exactly the same code.

This is similar to the problem reported here and in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159722/vsto-office-excel-add-in-wpf-xaml-style-resourcedictionary).

I'll share my findings in case it is of help to you. From various testing it seems that if the MahApp resources are placed in the UserControl or Window, they work. However placing them in my own resource dictionary and loading that dictionary in the user control does not work.

e.g. this works

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

but

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/IressWorkbook;component/Assets/MyTheme.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

does not, where MyTheme contains

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I am trying to track down what the difference is between the machines that work and the ones that don't.

Regards
Alan

Comment: I've had this problem before with VMs. Because WPF uses DirectX ensure the VM is setup accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I made it work this way:

1. add dictionaries at runtime

`wpfApp = new Application() { ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown }; wpfApp.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml") }); wpfApp.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml") }); wpfApp.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Themes/Light.Blue.xaml") });`

2. use DynamicResource in xaml

   `<ContentControl Foreground="{DynamicResource MahApps.Brushes.IdealForeground}" />`

Works in VS2019 with net48 vsto excel addin with O365 local install version 16.0.+